# ctable extensions: colored horizontal and extended vertical rules - need help

Tags: optional-arguments, ctable

I'm working on my `ctable` LaTeX package, planning to allow for optional `key=value`   arguments for `\FL`, `\ML`, `\LL`, such that one can make a `3pt` thick, red-colored toprule with `\FL[w=3pt,c=red]`; also, vertical rules should extend, unlike in the package  `booktabs`, currently used by `ctable`, where get broken.

My current problem is that I try to use `\@ifnextchar` to detect the optional argument.
My test below starts with a little demo that shows that `\@ifnextchar` hands over `\BB`'s optional argument to `\AA`.
But the same construct in my `\FL` hands over nothing, and the optional argument is printed as text, including the brackets. Could someone help me out please?
Here is my test:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{charter,xkeyval,colortbl}
\pagestyle{empty}\parindent0pt

\makeatletter

% for a demo of \@ifnextchar
% If \BB see an optional argument, it calls \AA with it.
% With no optional argument, \AA[default] is called.
\def\AA[#1]{===#1===}
\def\BB{\@ifnextchar[{\AA}{\AA[default]}}

\newlength\savedwidth
\define@key{rules}{w}{\global\savedwidth\arrayrulewidth\global\arrayrulewidth#1}
\define@key{rules}{c}{\gdef\rulecolor{#1}}

\def\XX[#1]{\setkeys{rules}{#1}}

\def\FL{%
  \noalign{%
    \setkeys{rules}{w=2pt,c=blue}   % set the defaults
    \@ifnextchar[{\XX}{}            % optional arg? call \XX with it
  }%
  \arrayrulecolor{\rulecolor}%
  \hline%
  \noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth\savedwidth} % restore width
  \arrayrulecolor{black}                  % and color
  \rule{0pt}{3ex}   % strut for extra whitespace under the rule
}

\begin{document}
% Here's the demo:
\BB[argument]\\\BB

\medskip
% now a table with a default toprule
\begin{tabular}{|r|l|}\FL
  Hello World & Here I am\\
Using FL with & no arg
\end{tabular}

\medskip
% and a table with a thick red toprule
\begin{tabular}{|r|l|}\FL[c=red,w=4pt]
  Hello World & Here I am\\
Using FL with & c=red
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\@ifnextchar` will never see the `[` after `\FL` because it will always see the closing brace of the `\noalign`. You need to open the `\noalign` but close it after detecting any optional arguments.

See

```
 \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
```

in `\hline` which uses the special brace trick for exactly this reason.

Also you want to move your `%` comments back next to the `}` as you have lots of spurious space tokens in your definition from the space before the comments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{charter,xkeyval,colortbl}
\pagestyle{empty}\parindent0pt

\makeatletter

% for a demo of \@ifnextchar
% If \BB see an optional argument, it calls \AA with it.
% With no optional argument, \AA[default] is called.
\def\AA[#1]{===#1===}
\def\BB{\@ifnextchar[{\AA}{\AA[default]}}

\newlength\savedwidth
\define@key{rules}{w}{\global\savedwidth\arrayrulewidth\global\arrayrulewidth#1}
\define@key{rules}{c}{\gdef\rulecolor{#1}}

\def\XX[#1]{\setkeys{rules}{#1}\XXX}
\def\XXX{\ifnum0=`{\fi}%
  \arrayrulecolor{\rulecolor}%
  \hline%
  \noalign{\global\arrayrulewidth\savedwidth}% restore width
  \arrayrulecolor{black}%                 % and color
  \rule{0pt}{3ex}%   % strut for extra whitespace under the rule
}

\def\FL{%
  \noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi
    \setkeys{rules}{w=2pt,c=blue}%   % set the defaults
    \@ifnextchar[{\XX}{\XXX} %           % optional arg? call \XX with it
}

\begin{document}
% Here's the demo:
\BB[argument]\\\BB

\medskip
% now a table with a default toprule
\begin{tabular}{|r|l|}\FL
  Hello World & Here I am\\
Using FL with & no arg
\end{tabular}

\medskip
% and a table with a thick red toprule
\begin{tabular}{|r|l|}\FL[c=red,w=4pt]
  Hello World & Here I am\\
Using FL with & c=red
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```